# Should `_base_manager` or `_default_manager` be preferred over `objects` in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/managers/#default-managers) :

> If you’re writing some code that must handle an unknown model, for example, in a third-party app that implements a generic view, use this manager (or _base_manager) rather than assuming the model has an objects manager.

Then isn't it a "good practice" to use `_base_manager` or `_default_manager` over using `objects` **always**? That way we need not worry in the code if the `objects` manager exists or not or if has been changed, etc?

If NOT, are there any benefits of using _base_manager? In which scenarios (other than that specified in the docs) should we generalize manager by using it and not `objects`.

Comment: If you know that `.objects` for a model exists, you typically use `.objects`. Sometimes the `.objects` is modified such that it returns a *subset* of the elements, for example for a "soft kill model".

Comment: That is True. But if we properly set the order of managers to be picked, then it should be the responsibility of `_base_manager` or `_default_mamanger` to give the right manager, in your case `objects`.

Comment: no, the `_default_manager` normally should always provide *all* objects, especially since a lot of Django code depends on that. But `.objects` sometimes is patched to give only a subset, or to make some default annotations, already, etc.